# How to skip a loop in kdb?

Tags: kdb

I have the following

```
mydata:raze {[x]

L: select from .... 

if[count[L] <= 20; continue]

} peach vals;
```

and I am trying to add an if-statement that would skip a particular entry in vals if the condition is not met. `continue`works well in matlab, but, I am not sure of the corresponding syntax in kdb. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [explicit return (:)](https://code.kx.com/q/basics/control/#explicit-return) in the if statement to return an empty list for those cases. Something like:

```
mydata:raze {[x]

L: select from .... 

if[count[L] <= 20; :()]

} peach vals;
```